# VSCode prettier adds `value` to imports in TypeScript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

After configuring prettier with the plugin in VSCode the format on save function adds weird `value` keywords to every non-default import in my React+TS code.

Like this:

```
import { value ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import { value BrowserRouter as Router, value Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Routes from './routes';
import { value client } from './data/apollo-config';
```

With this TS complains about `Duplicate identifier 'value'.ts(2300)`

Could anyone help me with this? Not sure why this is happening and how to solve it. Running `npx prettier --write someFile` doesn't add the `value` keywords.

My package.json:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@apollo/client": "^3.3.6",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "graphql": "^15.4.0",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
        "react-scripts": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "prettier": "^2.1.2",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.2",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
        "@types/lodash.merge": "^4.6.6",
        "@types/node": "^14.14.6",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.55",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
        "cypress": "^6.4.0",
        "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.3",
        "lodash.merge": "^4.6.2",
        "start-server-and-test": "^1.11.7",
        "typescript": "^4.5.4"
    },
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build"
  ],
  "typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "types": [
    "react",
    "react-dom",
    "react-dom-router",
    "jest",
    "node"
  ]
}
```

eslintrc.js

```
{
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser", // Specifies the ESLint parser
    "extends": [
        "react-app",
        "plugin:react/recommended", // Uses the recommended rules from @eslint-plugin-react
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended", // Uses the recommended rules from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin+   'prettier/@typescript-eslint',  // Uses eslint-config-prettier to disable ESLint rules from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin that would conflict with prettier
        "plugin:prettier/recommended" // Enables eslint-plugin-prettier and displays prettier errors as ESLint errors. Make sure this is always the last configuration in the extends array.
    ],
    "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "jest", "cypress"],
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
        "sourceType": "module", // Allows for the use of imports
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true // Allows for the parsing of JSX
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-redeclare": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/triple-slash-reference": "off"
    },
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "version": "detect" // Tells eslint-plugin-react to automatically detect the version of React to use
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue today, fixed it by restarting the editor (vscode in my case)

Comment: It happens with the prettier CLI too. Please update the question. This is an issue in prettier 2.5.1

Comment: Restarting wasn't working for me. I had to update a little old prettier I had in the project. Maybe VSCode was using it and went crazy.

Comment: I'm using a monorepo and I noticed that some repos had an older version of prettier than the main app was using.  Once I synced all versions to be 2.5.1 and restarted.  The problem went away.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

**Restarting the Extension Host** solved the problem for me.

To do so, open the Command Palette (default keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>) and search for:

> Developer: Restart Extension Host

Comment: Or simply restart IDE (with IntelliJ / WebStorm).

Comment: `Developer: Reload Window` worked for me

Answer (score 7):

I noticed TS 4.5.x in the dependencies. Things like this have been happening with versions of other libraries (e.g. prettier) that don't properly account for this TS change:

```
// < 4.5.0
import type { ThingType } from 'mylib';
import { Thing2 } from 'mylib';

// >= 4.5.0
import { type ThingType, Thing2 } from 'mylib';
```

The reason a restart is working for many people is that VSCode may keep a process alive from prior to an update. The process is killed when it closes, then, provided that compatible versions of prettier and ts are installed, it will work on restart. If it's still not working, you'll either have to upgrade prettier or downgrade TS until you can get a working set of dependencies cobbled together.

Comment: Downgrading to prettier 2.4.1 fixes the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

did you check your extensions? maybe you are using some auto import or some intellisense that has been replaced in some vscode update.
Could you check if you have prettier as default formatter in your vscode settings? and check where prettier library is coming from (node_modules, vscode lib, both?) maybe use .prettierrc file too, I have this settings in mine

```js
{
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": false,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "endOfLine": "auto",
  "proseWrap": "preserve",
  "printWidth": 100 //max width of linecode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prettier 2.6.0 is released now and fixes this issue. This was caused by an outdated TypeScript parser. Please upgrade prettier.

https://prettier.io/blog/2022/03/16/2.6.0.html#typescript

Comment: Do you have the source for the bug you're describing? The [changelog](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) doesn't mention this.

Comment: They don't mention this bug, but they updated the TypeScript parser to support parsing TypeScript 4.6, and that fixes the issue. https://prettier.io/blog/2022/03/16/2.6.0.html

Answer (score -1):

For me i chose Prettier - Code formater  as the default one

When i changed to Prettier - Eslint this fixed the issue.

[available formatters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVMmq.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).